# Is it safe to git clone https://usr:PWD@gitserver/repo with plain text passphrase in the URL?

Tags: security, passwords, git, https

Is it safe to

```
git clone https://usr:PWD@gitserver/repo
```

with plain text passphrase in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this would not be recommendable for several reasons:

- The password will be stored in your user's shell history file, which may end up backed up somewhere, and may be easily accessible to other users with root privileges.
- While you're cloning, the password is visible in plaintext in the local machine's process list, so any user doing a process listing would also be able to see it.

It's safer to [use the `store` helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) and use a `.git-credentials` file (that should of course be readable for your user only). This however will not prevent theft from root users with access to your data.

You can use [the `cache` helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) to save the passwords in memory for a certain amount of time (which is configurable). This is the safest variant, but requires you to re-enter your password after the timeout.